# Using WHERE in INSERT … ON CONFLICT …

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, upsert

I'm trying to use where clause with `insert on conflict` in PostgreSQL and it's not triggering. Here is my SQL query written in python. I'm using psycopg2:

```
INSERT INTO city_guide_stat AS stat (city_guide_id, {cols})
VALUES {values}
ON CONFLICT (city_guide_id)
DO UPDATE SET ({update_cols}) = ({update_values})
WHERE stat.city_guide_id = excluded.city_guide_id 
AND md5(({dest_hash_cols})::TEXT)<>md5(({src_hash_cols})::TEXT)
```

and here is my python code which actually fills these python variables:

```
sql_stmt = sql.SQL(UPSERT_CITY_GUIDE_STAT).format(
            # Table columns
            cols=sql.SQL(', ').join(
                map(sql.Identifier, COLUMNS_TO_INSERT_UPDATE)),
            # Values
            values=sql.SQL(', ').join(
                sql.SQL('({})').format(
                    sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * (num_columns)),
                ) * num_batch
            ),
            # Update columns
            update_cols=sql.SQL(', ').join(
                map(sql.Identifier, COLUMNS_TO_INSERT_UPDATE)),
            update_values=sql.SQL(', ').join(map(lambda x: sql.SQL('excluded.{}').format(
                sql.Identifier(x)
            ), COLUMNS_TO_INSERT_UPDATE)),
            # hash_cols
            dest_hash_cols=sql.SQL(', ').join(map(lambda x: sql.SQL('stat.{}').format(
                sql.Identifier(x)
            ), COLUMNS_TO_INSERT_UPDATE)),
            src_hash_cols=sql.SQL(', ').join(map(lambda x: sql.SQL('excluded.{}').format(
                sql.Identifier(x)
            ), COLUMNS_TO_INSERT_UPDATE))
        )
```

The problem I'm facing is that my where clause is not triggering.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is unnecessary, since the `ON CONFLICT` clause will only update one row at a time anyway. That's not the problem here, but simplifying the query will help. Try to get the exact SQL query, then it will be easier to debug the problem.

Comment: I'm matching md5 hashes to know either I need to update in table or not. if md5 matches then I don't need to update the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing md5 of text representation of rows is unreliable because input text can differ from output representation of equal rows, e.g. for numeric values:

```
md5('1.0') <> md5('1') while (1.0) = (1)
```

If all columns types have equality operator then compare rows:

```
INSERT INTO city_guide_stat AS stat (city_guide_id, {cols})
VALUES {values}
ON CONFLICT (city_guide_id)
DO UPDATE SET ({update_cols}) = ({update_values})
WHERE ({dest_hash_cols}) is distinct from ({src_hash_cols})
```

otherwise you cannot do that at all (or compare only comparable).

Note also, that

```
WHERE stat.city_guide_id = excluded.city_guide_id
```

is redundant.

Comment: I'm making sure that my values in column stay same on both sides, so I'm not expecting md5 change from both side due to a situation you mentioned above in the example.

Comment: The idea is just erroneous and it doesn't make sense to check whether it may work well in some cases.

Comment: Your solution worked all I have to do `COALESCE` for null values.

Comment: You can deal with nulls using `is distinct from`, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding more to your answer. Yes, that way I can deal with null values too.